# Responsiveness and side margins on big screens

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble developing a website using Bootstrap. I am currently trying to have a margin on the side, when the screen or viewport is too big. But when I finally got it, it broke the responsiveness of the page.

The whole body is inside this div to create the margins:

```
div style="width:1300px; margin:auto;"
```

Comment: You cannot put `<body>` into another HTML element. Put `style="width:1300px; margin:auto;"` on the `body` element instead.

Comment: sorry, about my english, not main languaje, y meant like this <body><div></div></body>

Comment: Use `max-width` instead.

Comment: Please mark @connexo's answer as correct if this worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Add this media query to your CSS and make sure it's referenced **after** any other CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  body {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```